# No response when query elasticsearch with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have some code to query specific strings in a field `message` as below:

```
"message": "Oct 29 11:38:46 1893 192.168.1.114 TCP_MISS/200 153925 GET http://www.pravda.ru/science/ - DIRECT/185.103.135.90 text/html"
```

Here is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json

client = Elasticsearch(['http://192.168.1.114:9200'])

response = client.search(
  index="squidlog-2017.10.29",
  body={
      "query": {
          "match": {
            "message": 'GET'
          }
      }
  }
)

for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
    print json.dumps(hit['_source'], indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

When I query with specific strings: GET with template above, everything is ok. But when I want to query something about url in message, I don't receive anything, like for the following query:

```
body={
      "query": {
          "match": {
            "message": 'pravda'
          }
      }
  }
```

Is there any problem with slashes in my message when I query? Anyone please give me an advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a different [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-tokenizers.html), which will make the desired search possible. But let me explain why your query does not return you the result in the second case.

#### `standard` analyzer and tokenizer

By default [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) consists of [`standard` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html), which will apparently keep the domain name not split by dots. You can try different analyzers and tokenizers with [`_analyze`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-analyze.html) endpoint, like this:

```
GET _analyze
{
    "text": "Oct 29 11:38:46 1893 192.168.1.114 TCP_MISS/200 153925 GET http://www.pravda.ru/science/ - DIRECT/185.103.135.90 text/html"
}
```

The response is a list of tokens that ElasticSearch will be using to represent this string while searching. Here it is:

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "oct",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      }, ...
      {
         "token": "http",
         "start_offset": 59,
         "end_offset": 63,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 11
      },
      {
         "token": "www.pravda.ru",
         "start_offset": 66,
         "end_offset": 79,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 12
      },
      {
         "token": "science",
         "start_offset": 80,
         "end_offset": 87,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 13
      }, ...
   ]
}
```

As you can see, `"pravda"` is not in the list of tokens, hence you cannot search for it. You can only search for the tokens that your analyzer emits.

Note that `"pravda"` is part of the domain name, which is a analyzed as a separate token: `"www.pravda.ru"`.

#### `lowercase` tokenizer

If you use different tokenizer, for instance, `lowercase` tokenizer, it will do emit `pravda` as a token and it will be possible to search for it:

```
GET _analyze
{
    "tokenizer" : "lowercase",
    "text": "Oct 29 11:38:46 1893 192.168.1.114 TCP_MISS/200 153925 GET http://www.pravda.ru/science/ - DIRECT/185.103.135.90 text/html"
}
```

And the list of tokens:

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "oct",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 0
      }, ...
      {
         "token": "http",
         "start_offset": 59,
         "end_offset": 63,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "www",
         "start_offset": 66,
         "end_offset": 69,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 5
      },
      {
         "token": "pravda",
         "start_offset": 70,
         "end_offset": 76,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 6
      },
      {
         "token": "ru",
         "start_offset": 77,
         "end_offset": 79,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 7
      },
      {
         "token": "science",
         "start_offset": 80,
         "end_offset": 87,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 8
      }, ...
   ]
}
```

#### How to define analyzer before indexing?

To be able to search for such tokens, you have to analyze them during the index phase differently. It means to define a different mapping with different analyzer. Like in this example:

```
PUT yet_another_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_custom_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "lowercase"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "message": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                  "lowercased": {
                     "type": "text",
                     "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here, we first define a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) with desired tokenizer, and then tell ElasticSearch to index our `message` field twice via [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/multi-fields.html) feature: implicitly with default analyzer, and explicitly with `my_custom_analyzer`.

Now we are able to query for the desired token. Request to the original field will give no response:

```
POST yet_another_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "message": "pravda"
        }
    }
}

   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
```

But the query to the `message.lowercased` will succeed:

```
POST yet_another_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "message.lowercased": "pravda"
        }
    }
}

   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.25316024,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "yet_another_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "AV9u1qZmB9pi5Gaw0rj1",
            "_score": 0.25316024,
            "_source": {
               "message": "Oct 29 11:38:46 1893 192.168.1.114 TCP_MISS/200 153925 GET http://www.pravda.ru/science/ - DIRECT/185.103.135.90 text/html"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

There are plenty of options, this solution answers the example you provided. Check out different analyzers and tokenizers to find which one suits you more.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent!!!. Understanding more with your explaination, now I can solve my problem. Thanks very much bro.